# creating dynamic array in php

Tags: php, arrays, variables, dynamic

I have following records in text file, need to extract that record form text file and treat them as seperate array variables

`r1=(1,2,3)|r2=(4,5,6)|r3=(1,2,3,4,5,7)|rn=(9,6,7,8)` seperated by pipe(|)

I need to represent that as array use seperately like below

```
$r1= Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 2
[2] => 3
)

$r2=Array
(
[0] => 4
[1] => 5
[2] => 6
)
```

I have no idea how to do it, is it possible in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Eval

```
//Assuming  you can pull the content from text file using fread

$temp = "r1=(1,2,3)|r2=(4,5,6)";
$temp=str_replace("=","=array",$temp);
$split=explode("|",$temp);
echo "<pre>";
foreach($split as $k=>$v){
      $v="$".$v.";";
      //Evaluate a string as PHP code .i.e You will get r1,r2 as a variable now which is array
      eval($v);
}

print_r($r1);
print_r($r2);
```

Comment: amazing! now i can acess all those r1,r2,r3 as $r1,$r2,$r3. Thank you

Comment: go with jack's logic its even better

Answer (score 1):

Just a plain regular expression to break up the string, followed by an explode on each group:

```
if (preg_match_all('#(\w+)=\(([\d,]*)\)#', $s, $matches)) {
    foreach ($matches[2] as $i => $groups) {
        $group_name = $matches[1][$i];
        $$group_name = array_map('intval', explode(',', $groups));
    }
}

print_r($r1);
print_r($r3);
print_r($rn);
```

Comment: good one , can it be edited to make those r1,r2 and r3 as seperate variable , i am just curious

Comment: @timus2001 I've added a second part to the answer that also extracts the group name. Is that what you meant?

Comment: still no :) , (s)he need all arrays as seperate variable  like $r1,$r2.. small eval is needed ... i got the solution but if some line added to your code its even more generic

Comment: its really awesome, hats off logic :)

Comment: thank you sir, it worked . But as a beginner i found regular expression tough

Comment: @KhagendraThapamagar regular expressions basically do what you wouldn't want to write yourself, that's why the syntax can be somewhat intimidating; but just practice it, it's fun .. one regex per day :0

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = "r1=(1,2,3)|r2=(4,5,6)|r3=(1,2,3,4,5,7)|rn=(9,6,7,8)";

$arr = explode("|", $data);

$finArray = array();

foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
{
    $single = explode('(', $value);
    $finArray[] = explode(',', str_replace(')', '', $single[1]));
}

print_r($finArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you:--

```
  <?php
    $file = "/tmp/file1.txt"; // this is your file path
    $f = fopen($file, "r");
    while ( $line = fgets($f, 1000) ) {
    print $line;

    $a=explode('|',$line);
    print_r($a);  // I have explode based on | for you...

foreach($a as $key=>$value)
{
    print_r($value);
}
```

fclose($file);
        }
        ?>

""or""

```
$a="r1=(1,2,3)|r2=(4,5,6)|r3=(1,2,3,4,5,7)|rn=(9,6,7,8)";

$a=explode('|',$a);
print_r($a);
```

Comment: @timus2001 i am just giving rough idea how to do that.. not doing full code .. understand..

Comment: (s)he need $r1,$r2 ,$rn as seperate array :)

Comment: hmm the logic is we need to change each element of array as one seperate array , please check Eval function in php

Comment: thank you for your effort sir  though its not what i need, timus2001 is 100% correct

Answer (score 0):

can be done as:

```
$string="r1=(1,2,3)|r2=(4,5,6)|r3=(1,2,3,4,5,7)|rn=(9,6,7,8)";
$string=str_repla("r1=","",$string);
$yourArray=explode('|', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
$file = "file.txt";
$f = fopen($file, "r");
while ( $line = fgets($f, 1000) ) {
$str = $line;
}
$str1 = explode("|",$str);
foreach($str1 as $temp) {
    $str2 = explode("=",$temp);
    $data[$str2[0]] = explode(",",trim($str2[1],"()"));
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

This will do your job.